# Laravel - Express - React Comunication

Tags: reactjs, laravel, express, axios, laravel-excel

I'm doing an experiment were I have 3 servers:

- Using Laravel (backend with Laravel-Excel)
- Using ExpressJS (with axios)
- Using React JS (FrontEnd)

My objective is to use the `laravel-excel` library and export the database tables directly into an excel file and download it.

In the laravel server, I'm using the line of code:

```
Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
```

This line of code works, but I'm having trouble send the exported file request to the react js server.

In the ExpressJS I've tried:

```
app.post('/GetExportExcel', function (req, res) {

    axios.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/ExportandDownloadFile',
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://localhost:3000/",
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        },
        //responseType: 'stream'
        responseType: 'blob', // important
    })
    .then(response =>{

        response.data.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if (error.response) {
            res.status(error.response.status).json(error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) { 
            res.status(502).end();
        } else { 
            res.status(500).end();
        }
    });
});
```

and in the react JS:

```
static ExportExcelFile()
{
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');  

    return fetch('http://localhost:4500/GetExportExcel',{
        timeout: 2000,
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers,
    }).then(response => {

        response.blob().then(blob => {
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'users.xlsx');
        });
    });
}
```

And So far, the contents of the exported file haven't reached the frontend (reactJS server). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers have two `http` strings in front of your url `http://http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Thank You, i've corrected the url.